# object element does not catch jQuery events?

Tags: jquery, html

I have svg images embedded in  elements in html files. When the user clicks on the object/image, I want to have a click event that enlarges the image. I have the functionality working, but I cannot get the object element to catch the click event. The only time this works is if I have another element wrapping the object, which has e.g. an image caption or the like. Then the surrounding area with the caption is clickable if I put the event on there instead. But not all images have such an area, and it is still a nuisance, because it makes it hard to know where you should click.

So my question: how can I make the object element clickable to execute jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery's event system requires that a DOM element allow attaching data via a property on the element, so that events can be tracked and delivered. The object, embed, and applet elements cannot attach data, and therefore cannot have jQuery events bound to them.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Ok. So the link you provided, is that the answer? Does that imply a workaround? I'm sorry I didn't understand it very well. If it is a workaround, could you please give an example how I would use it?

Comment: Yes, assuming I understand your problem. The short version of the answer is "you can't" and you'll probably have to go with a workaround. Wrapping the object elements with other elements would be one way to do that, as you mentioned yourself.

Comment: Right. Well, I noticed now that the link was not a workaround, but rather an explanation of the problem. And well, wrapping it would work with some padding or something, but it would require the user to click outside the image rather than on it... I would like a workaround for clicking the actual image. There isn't something (invisible) that I can put as a layer on top of it that's clickable or something?

Comment: The event from wrapping element should be enough if you are consistent with the HTML structure that you generate. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2uBy3/11/

Comment: Well, that's very strange... I can see that your jsfiddle example is working, but I cannot get it to work in my code. I tried a very simple version of yours: $('.fig').on('click', function(){
    alert('testing');
}); And actually, just inserting that broke the jQuery code, so none of the jQuery works...

Comment: Are you running the latest version of jQuery? I think the `.on()` function was introduced not long ago. Also, checking for exact error message would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't running the latest version, but I changed to it, and that made the function work. But still only if I had some text or something around the svg image, creating a sort of padding around the object where I could click. $(".fig").on("click", function () {
        $(this).find("object").css({
            "background": "green"
        });
    }); But I still can't click the actual image, then nothing happens...

Answer (score -1):

The way that I've worked around this jQuery feature/limitation is to not use jQuery for events on the  element.  For example the following works:

After the page loads,

```
var ajqueryobject = $('object');
ajqueryobject[0].addEventListener('load', function(ev){/*content*/}) ;
```